# Cannot start neo4j 3.0.0 on Gentoo

Tags: neo4j

Running `/neo4jhome/bin/neo4j console` I get `./neo4j: line 219: cd: logs: No such file or directory`. I have Java 8 installed, and I tried making a directory called `logs` to the same error. How do I properly start neo4j?

Answer (score 0):

Edit bash script and print current directory by echo $PWD command, then go to directory which script printed out and create directory logs aka mkdir logs